# Module to display file from an SVN repo?

Tags: files

Looking for a way to display text files that are stored in an SVN repo or local filesystem. Exactly like http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Include works for mediawiki.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at 
[Version Control API](http://drupal.org/project/versioncontrol) with [Version Control API -- Subversion backend](http://drupal.org/project/versioncontrol_svn)

I didn't use it but you can try

> This module provides an implementation of the Version Control API that
>   makes it possible to use the Subversion revision control system.

P.S. Drupal 5 and 6 only